# Slice the string if it contains Particular Format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, split

I want a write a generic JavaScript method which will remove the string which contains a specific pattern, for example

Good Morning . **On Thu, Sep 7, 2017 at 8:01 PM, <abc@gmail.com> wrote:** Thank you.. HELLO 6 -- Thanks and Regards, Pawan R

HELLO 7.. saying hello6 received. **On Mon, Oct 10, 2016 at 9:01 PM, <abc@gmail.com> wrote:** Thank you very much Thanks and Regards, Pawan R

The method should give me the Output **HELLO 7.. saying hello6 received**. **Good Morning** for the above example

I can use the slice method of JavaScript but how to pass a format like the above.

Comment: What effort have you made so far?

Comment: str.slice(0, Data.snippet.indexOf("On Mon, Oct 10, 2016 at 9:01 PM, <abc@gmail.com> wrote:")); but i want to match the pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to find it

```js
let str = 'Good Morning . On Thu, Sep 7, 2017 at 8:01 PM, <abc@gmail.com> wrote: Thank you.. HELLO 6 -- Thanks and Regards, Pawan R'

let str2 = 'HELLO 7.. saying hello6 received. On Mon, Oct 10, 2016 at 9:01 PM, <abc@gmail.com> wrote: Thank you very much Thanks and Regards, Pawan R'

console.log(str.match(/^.*(?=\. On (?:Thu|Mon))/));
console.log(str2.match(/^.*(?=\. On (?:Thu|Mon))/));
```

It matches the regex for the particular format. You can edit the regex to add the rules since I covered only Thu and Mon

Comment: Can we guarantee that part of the string is always the same?

Comment: no it will keep on changing the only thing it follows is On Thu, Sep 7, 2017 at 8:01 PM, <abc@gmail.com> wrote:///On Mon, Oct 10, 2016 at 9:01 PM, <abc@gmail.com> wrote:

Comment: can we also have a condition that this pattern is available then only do the matches? Something like                                                                               if (str.indexOf("/^.*(?=\. On (?:Thu|Mon))/") !== -1)){
  var message = str.match(/^.*(?=\. On (?:Thu|Mon))/);

Comment: if pattern does not match, it would return null